# Perforce P4HOST won't work from Config file, only globally

Tags: perforce, assembla

I have a connection to Assembla that requires P4HOST to be set. I have a bunch of other P4 connections to different servers that don't need that set.

I've setup a few different p4config.txt files and set P4CONFIG to use that file name.

Everything on my connections works well, and everything returns proper with "p4 set" within each directory.

But the problem is with the Assembla config file. It returns everything fine from "p4 set", but still can't connect. It can't seem to get the Host properly. But "p4 set" reports otherwise. I set the Host globally with "p4 set host hostName", but that is not ideal since it breaks the other connections.

What's the best way to proceed here? I'm confused why the Host isn't working in the text file.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is that the config setting is being set **multiple** times, and Perforce is choosing the first setting (or the last), and the one it's choosing is not the one you want. Try `p4 -vrpc=3 help` from a command line using your Assembla configuration and see if you can see multiple values for your hostname setting.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known P4V bug.

Basically pv4 doesn't take P4HOST from the config file properly. Assembla needs HOST to be set to route the request to correct spot given a global URL across the user base. I recommend running this from command line or from a context like UE4 editor.

```
export P4HOST=space_name && /Applications/P4/p4v.app/Contents/MacOS/p4v
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and heads' up on P4HOST being buggy from config. However "export" isn't a Windows command that works from the Prompt.

Comment: Try SET in windows.